# How to identify Modbus device speed rate?

Tags: rs485, serial-bus, modbus

In particular how to identify it without causing device misbehaving.

Either new device is being connected, and master has no idea what baud rate the device is configured with (assume it knows about 8/N/1 configuration), or device was switched to some non-default speed, and then master was rebooted and forgot about what setting there was in the slave.

Trying various speeds with some predefined command would be an answer, but there's still tiny probability that device will accept the erroneous command and do something unexpected, or just hang or, as the worst, hang the communication line.

Comment: It would be a poor Modbus implementation if it misbehaved due to wrong baud rate considering RTU uses a 16bit CRC to ensure validity.

Comment: There's still 0.0015% of probability that CRC16 matches and command is executed.